# Display bottom canvas with a shadow effect - shadow within clipped area

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I`m new with canvas so thanks for your patience.

I wrote an engine that is creating 2 different layers in 2 canvas elements which are one over another. They contain some generated pictures, which aren`t important here.
[image: They are on over another]

I'm trying to create an effect which will display bottom layer when I move mouse over the top layer and click.

Something like this:
[image]

This is what I have tried so far:

1. To use transparency on canvas element and display bottom canvas (fast but not usable)
2. Re-create a clipping region.
   Whenever I press the mouse I store current coordinates and re-render the canvas with updated clipping region

Updating clipping region is slow if I use stroke to create shadows + I`m not sure how to remove lines from it (see picture).
[image: Lines show up]

If I remove shadow effect, it works really fast, but I need to have it.

The only thing that comes on my mind how to speed this, is to save coordinates of every click, and then to re-calculate that into 1 shape and drop a shadow on it - I`ll still have lines, but it will be faster because there won`t be thousand of circles to draw...

**Any help will be most appreciated!**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take advantage of the browser's built in interpolation by using it as a pseudo low-pass filter, but first by painting it black:

- Copy the top layer to the bottom layer
- Set source-in comp. mode
- Draw all black
- Set source-in comp. mode
- Scale down image to 25%
- Scale the 25% region back up to 50% of original (or double of current)
- Scale the now 50% region back up to 100% of original. It will be blurred.

Depending on how much blur you want you can add additional steps. That being said: blurred shadow is an intensive operation no matter how it is twisted and turned. One can make compromise to only render the shadow on mouse up for example (as in the demo below).

## Example

Example using two layers. Top layer let you draw anything, bottom will show shadow version at the bottom later while drawing.

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("top").getContext("2d"),
    bctx = document.getElementById("bottom").getContext("2d"),
    bg = new Image(),
    isDown = false;

bg.src = "http://i.imgur.com/R2naCpK.png";

ctx.fillStyle = "#27f";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-out";  // "eraser"

ctx.canvas.onmousedown = function(e) {isDown = true};

window.onmousemove = function(e) {
  if (!isDown) return;
  var pos = getPos(ctx.canvas, e);
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(pos.x + 10, pos.y);
  ctx.arc(pos.x, pos.y, 10, 0, 2*Math.PI);         // erase while drawing
  ctx.fill();  
};

window.onmouseup = function(e) {
  if (isDown) {
    isDown = false;
    makeShadow();
  }
};

function makeShadow(){
  var w = bctx.canvas.width,
      h = bctx.canvas.height,
      offset = 7, 
      alpha = 0.75;
  
  // reset alpha
  bctx.globalAlpha = 1;

  // normal comp mode to clear as it is faster than using "copy"
  bctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
  bctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);

  // copy top-layer to bottom-layer
  bctx.drawImage(ctx.canvas, 0, 0);
  
  // comp. mode will only draw in to non-alpha pixels next
  bctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-in";
  
  // black overlay
  bctx.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
  
  // copy mode so we don't need an extra canvas
  bctx.globalCompositeOperation = "copy";
  
  // step 1: reduce to 50% (quality related - create more steps to increase blur/quality)
  bctx.drawImage(bctx.canvas, 0, 0, w, h, 0, 0, w * 0.5, h * 0.5);
  
  bctx.drawImage(bctx.canvas, 0, 0, w * 0.5, h * 0.5, 0, 0, w * 0.25, h * 0.25);
  bctx.drawImage(bctx.canvas, 0, 0, w * 0.25, h * 0.25, 0, 0, w * 0.5, h * 0.5);
  
  // shadow transparency
  bctx.globalAlpha = alpha;
  
  // step 2: draw back up to 100%, draw offset
  bctx.drawImage(bctx.canvas, 0, 0, w * 0.5, h * 0.5, offset, offset, w, h);

  // comp in background image
  bctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-over";
  bctx.drawImage(bg, 0, 0, w, h);
}

function getPos(canvas, e) {
  var r = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  return {x: e.clientX - r.left, y: e.clientY - r.top};
}
```

```css
div {position:relative;border:1px solid #000;width:500px;height:500px}
canvas {position:absolute;left:0;top:0}
#bottom {background:#eee}
```

```html
<div>
  <canvas id="bottom" width=500 height=500></canvas>
  <canvas id="top" width=500 height=500></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: Omg, this looks amazing! I`ll need to check it later, but THANK YOU for this!

Comment: Upvote for cool effect and nice application of compositing. BTW, your demo would be even cooler if you did something like: `#bottom {background-image:url('someCoolBackground.png');}` instead of #eee. :-)

Comment: Just thought to let you know that this helped a lot. I have photos in both layers,  so I had to create 3rd one for the shadow. I copied bottom layer to new one, and run your effect on it. Do you think it can be done with just 2 of them?

Comment: @GoranUsljebrka no problem! Yes, draw the shadow as usual, then change the comp mode of the bottom layer to destination-over, then draw the bottom image in (remember to switch back to source-over). (updated answer)

Comment: I see that you have updated a demo with background image.
In my case, I have a generated frame (it`s not just a picture, but unique frame), which takes a bit of resources to be created, so I think (I didn`t test it yet) that it`s "cheaper" to copy it to another one, then to re-create it...
I will really need to test this all in detail (at some point) but for now I`m thrilled that it works as it does. :-)